# From where comes "QXcbConnection: XCB error:" message and how fix it?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyqt5, xvfb

In CI tests, using Xvfb, I get various message as:

```
XcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 1448, resource id: 2097187, major code: 42 (SetInputFocus), minor code: 0
```

I have not yet been really able to find out exactly what these messages mean.

*What is the reason for these messages?*

While investigating during the tests it seems that this happens, among other things, when we virtually press a button to close a widget. For example by doing:

```
QTest.mouseClick(MyObject.push_button_ok, Qt.LeftButton)
```

*How to remove these messages?*

Comment: If the messages are being produced by Qt, you could use [qInstallMessageHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) to filter them. There's also [QLoggingCategory](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html).

Comment: This sounds promising. I'm going to look into this possibility that I didn't know about, very quickly. Thank you!